# get timestamp of files presented by FOR loop

Tags: stat, for

My aim is to find $files on some $devices and save them to one or more folders which are namend corresponding to a timestamp of each file. To get the timestamp I wanted to use stat.

In contrast to echo "$files", stat doesn't process each file separately. Instead it seems to process all files at once when I use "".

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve quoting or any other hints on how to make stat able to do what i want it to do? Thank you very much for your help.

```
#!/bin/bash
for devices in "$(ls /media/*/)";
  do
    for files in "$(find /media/*/$devices -iname *.jpg)";
      do
        echo "$files"   # prints all files in separate lines
        stat "$files"   # seems to process all files at once
        stat $files     # splits file paths at spaces
      done
  done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `stat` but with the source data in your `for` loop; because you have enclosed it all in quotes it becomes one long single entity.

To fix this, remove the quotes around it, thus:

```
for files in $(find /media/*/$devices -iname "*.jpg");
```

It works provided that none of the files or paths have spaces. But there is a more elegant solution which works with spaces and even with weird filenames (for instance ones that include quotes or newlines):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    # operations on each "$file" here
done < <(find /media/*/$devices -type f -iname *.jpg -print0)
```

Comment: re alternate suggestion: that's because this uses $file not $files, which is really better since each $file is an individual file. I'm revising my initial suggestion, but the alternate is better really.

Comment: Your alternate suggestion works for me (filenames with spaces) very well, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You can't distinguish a newline introduced by `ls` from a newline in a file name. The same goes for `find`.

`for devices in $(ls /media/*/)` is just a complex, broken way of writing `for devices in /media/*/*`. Instead of `for files in $(find …); do …; done`, use `find … -exec …`.

You don't need the two loops here, since you're only enumerating files in order to use the full set later. Your script is simply

```
find /media/*/* -iname '*.jpg' -exec stat {} +
```

For more information, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)